# ASP.NET MVC 4 alternative data handling (oracle ADF like)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, web-applications, oracle-adf

I'm building a web app, and I have objects that are 'bound' to screens (conceptually).
However, the only way I can save an object that has been changed on the screen (or a new one created) is with using forms and sending it to the controller. 
If i want to go to the next record, I have to request a new page, with paremeters where record = currentrecord + 1 (the Id).

There are applications like oracle ADF and some web applications that work differently in the sense that a screen is linked to an object, and you can do 'insert, delete, edit, next/previous'  without re-loading the page (requesting an URL with parameters).

I have no clue what the options are for MVC, any ideas any one? I do know those apps dont work with AJAX or some async method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stateless nature of the internet makes it such that every change on the client requires a new request from a server. Oracle ADF indeed uses AJAX, but its environment abstracts the ajax away from the developer so that s/he can focus on business logic. For example, when ADF does a partial page refresh, it sends/receives an AJAX request.

Some tricks are available for circumventing the need to request a page for each new record. One option is to load multiple records at a time and use hidden divs to encapsulate each record's data. Jquery has some options for this as well. If you can afford it, Telerik looks offers some really great tools to achieve your goals.

I would also recommend looking into display templates and editor templates--especially if you have a parent record with many child records.

Comment: Thanks, maybe Ill do some research into some page-wide ajax handling :) If not, I'll go with the usual route